# Change Woocommerce Email Template Text

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming, woocommerce-email

I got an email from woocommerce order like this:

[image]

I want to change `Billing address` text into `Delivery address` where could I change that text ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this question has been asked 2 years ago, but I want to answer it in case somebody else is interested how to do it:

WooCommerce 3.4.4

You can edit the text "Billing address" and "Shipping address" in the `email-addresses.php`.

Go to `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-addresses.php` and copy the file to your child theme folder `wp-content/themes/child-theme/woocommerce/emails/`. Open the file and replace the text "Billing address" or "Shipping address" to whatever you like!

Answer (score 1):

I Made it! After following some logic I found the text I needed to change here:

```
/home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-addresses.php
```

You can see it in the Screenshot

Change Billing address to Delivery address:

[image]

Hope this helps someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

You can visit this section in your WP-admin dashboard: `WooCommerce -> Settings -> Emails` to view and edit some WooCommerce Email template settings.

If you want to edit HTML template of this Emails, then you need edit files in this directory on your webserver: `woocommerce/templates/emails/`.

Please keep in mind that it is not good idea to edit the plugin files, because after plugin updating your changes can be overwritten.

So best way to edit WooCommerce Email HTML templates is: 
copy template PHP file, what you want to edit, from `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/` to your child theme folder: `wp-content/themes/child-theme/woocommerce/emails/` and edit it here.

Comment: I already make override that template but I stil dont know where I can change `Billing address` text to `Delivery address` text

Comment: admin-new-order.php

Comment: I just want to chane label `Billing address` to `Delivery address`

Comment: Try to edit this file: `email-customer-details.php`.

Comment: I just open `email-customer-details.php` but I still dont know where is the part of code to change the label `Billing address`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question @Alex

Comment: You shouldn't change the label of the Billing address to the Delivery address.